# Delete application data on iOS simulator without uninstalling app?

Tags: ios, react-native

I would like to **delete application data** like local storage without reinstalling the app.

I am using AsyncStorage in react-native, and have persisted some data. To quickly test storage, I would like to be able to clear AsyncStorage manually through the simulator, without implementing a logout/ clear AsyncStorage button in the app.
([React-Native AsyncStorage.clear() is failing on IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736268/react-native-asyncstorage-clear-is-failing-on-ios)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no easy way to do it, I have added a developer menu in my app, with a button called clear AsyncStorage, which called `AsyncStorage.clear()`.